# Given a number, getting a grid position in a spiral pattern

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  20       | id:  19       | id:  18       | id:  17       | id:  16       |
| pos: (-2, -2) | pos: (-1, -2) | pos: (0, -2)  | pos: (1, -2)  | pos: (2, -2)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  21       | id:  6        | id:  5        | id:  4        | id:  15       |
| pos: (-2, -1) | pos: (-1, -1) | pos: (0, -1)  | pos: (1, -1)  | pos: (2, -1)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  22       | id:  7        | id:  0        | id:  3        | id:  14       |
| pos: (-2, 0)  | pos: (-1, 0)  | pos: (0, 0)   | pos: (1, 0)   | pos: (2, 0)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  23       | id:  8        | id:  1        | id:  2        | id:  13       |
| pos: (-2, 1)  | pos: (-1, 1)  | pos: (0, 1)   | pos: (1, 1)   | pos: (2, 1)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  24       | id:  9        | id:  10       | id:  11       | id:  12       |
| pos: (-2, 2)  | pos: (-1, 2)  | pos: (0, 2)   | pos: (1, 2)   | pos: (2, 2)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Given the grid above how do you get the position based on the id? My implementation:

```
function getRing (id) {
 return Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(id + 1) - 1) / 2);
}

function getMinRingID (r) {
 if (r == 0) {
   return 0;
 }
 return Math.pow((2 * (r - 1) + 1), 2);
}

function getRingLegFromID (id) {
 if (id == 0) {
   return 0;
 }

 var r = getRing(id);
 var m = getMinRingID(r);
 if (id >= m && id < m + (2 * r)) {
   return 0;
 } else if (id >=  m + (2 * r) && id <  m + (4 * r)) {
   return 1;
 } else if (id >=  m + (4 * r) && id <  m + (6 * r)) {
   return 2;
 } else if (id >=  m + (6 * r)) {
   return 3;
 }
}
```

With the above basics, you can get the position with...

```
function getPos (id) {
 var ring = getRing(id);
 var min = getMinRingID(ring);
 var leg = getRingLegFromID(id);

 if (id === 0) {
   return [0, 0];
 }

 switch (leg) {
   case 0:
     return [-ring + ((id - min) + 1), ring];
     break;
   case 1:
     return [ring, ring - ((id - min) - ((2 * ring) - 1))];
     break;
   case 2:
     return [ring - ((id - min) - ((4 * ring) - 1)), -ring];
     break;
   case 3:
     return [-ring, -ring + ((id - min) - ((6 * ring) - 1))];
     break;
 }
}
```

Are there any optimizations I can make to this code? Is there just a better way to get the position from the id?

Comment: Will the grid always be 5 x 5? If not, is it always a square(`N x N`)? Is there an upper bound on the value of `N`?

Comment: @EricNa (`N x N`) and no, pos `x` and `y` are `int`s so just that limit.

Answer (score -1):

If the function is going to be called repeatedly and `N` is within a reasonable range (let's say 300), you can do a spiral walk for that upper bound `N` to calculate the `index` -> `position` mapping, cache it in a dictionary, and look it up.

For the spiral walk, you can do something similar to [this](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/solutions/python/spiral_matrix.py).

In case `x` or `y` values are larger than 300, you can use your function.

Comment: Please do not post links to code, post the code directly in your answer.